# Apache File Does Not Exist workaround

Tags: python, apache, flask

I have an app that calls upon the extension found [here](https://github.com/dantezhu/flask_util_js). I have the `.py` file in my `/var/www` folder so that it can be imported in my python code.

So, I keep getting this error:

```
File does not exist: /var/www/flask_util.js
```

in my apache error logs. It looks like, because of the name or something, it wants to find a javascript file. But, it's in python. Here's the line of code in python that import it:

```
from flask_util_js import FlaskUtilJs
```

I've tried just changing the name of the file to `flask_util.js`, but again, nothing. Not entirely sure what is going on here, but I am sure that I have a file in `/var/www` that it should be reading.

---

**EDIT**

I think, actually that the import error is coming from importing it into my HTML when I do this:

```
{{flask_util_js.js}}
```

So, what I tried was copy out the JS code from the python and create a new file with it in the correct path. When I did that, I still got the same error on the webpage, however the apache logs don't say anything (which is weird right?). So, it still doesn't work, and I don't know why

Comment: Just out of curiosity what framework or cgi are you using?

Comment: I'm using python Flask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's ugly but what I ended up doing was copying over the generated JS file that I could find on my server (didn't actually exist as a document in my repository). Then, apache could find it.

This part is for anyone who is actually using `flask_util_js`:

However, it wasn't reading in the correct Javascript for the url_mapping so I had to go in a hard-code the correct URLs. Not very scalable, but oh well.